# How can I list visible windows and their ID?

Tags: windows, cygwin

Being a linux fan, when I have to work on windows I use cygwin and a virtual desktop called [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/). I have it set up so that I have 12 active desktops (two screens each) and can quickly switch using Alt-F1 .. Alt-F12.

Now, since it's windows, it has to be rebooted on a regular basis.  Every time that happens, I need to relaunch dozens of applications and move them to the desktop I'm used to have them on (e.g. eclipse and other code-dev on #1, R on #3, chrome on #4, outlook on #8, etc.)  What I'd like to do is write a script that opens all these applications and moves their windows to the appropriate desktop.

I saw that there is a command-line use of VirtuaWin to effect certain functions on open windows, i.e. `VirtuaWin.exe -msg <Msg> <wParam> <lParam>` where "`<Msg>`, `<wParam>` and `<lParam>` are numbers as per the standard Windows SendMessage function" (as per the help built in VirtuaWin).  Apparently, `VirtuaWin.exe -msg 1049 $wn 2` would move window with the ID `$wn` to the 2nd desktop.

Great. But the question is: how, from e.g. a bash script, do I get the window IDs for each application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'll find this example useful.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {

  printf("HWND: %u\n", hwnd);

  char className[256];
  if (GetClassName(hwnd, className, sizeof className) == 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "GetClassName failed.\n");
  else
    printf("Class Name: %s\n", className);

  char windowText[256];  // text in the window's title bar
  if (GetWindowText(hwnd, windowText, sizeof windowText) == 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "GetWindowText failed.\n");
  else
    printf("Window Text: %s\n", windowText);

  putchar('\n');

  return TRUE;
}


int main() {

  BOOL ret = EnumDesktopWindows(
    NULL,             // Desktop to enumerate (NULL is default)
    EnumWindowsProc,  // Callback function
    0);               // lParam value to callback function

  if (ret == 0) fprintf(stderr, "EnumDesktopWindows failed.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ooga but I was looking for something that I would run from the cygwin bash command line.  Is there no such command?  I'm trying to keep any windows investment to a strict minimum and not really looking to set up a C development environment on windows...

Comment: I don't know if there is such a command. But since you already have cygwin installed it would be a small step to install gcc and compile and run the above program.

Comment: Awesome! Much simpler than I thought, in fact I already had gcc installed. Thanks a lot!  For sake of completeness, here is what I did: 1. check that gcc was installed (`gcc --version` outputs 4.8.2). 2. cat @ooga's code into wlist.c  3. `gcc -o wlist wlist.c`  4. `./wlist`   and it works flawlessly. Now what I need to do is edit the source to output something else than "Default IME" as the window text.